# System logs out instead of sleep/suspend

Tags: suspend, power-management

For the last few weeks or so, whenever I try to put computer to sleep it logs out instead. But writing `sudo pm-suspend` in Terminal works, computer sleeps normally.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  --since="-10 minutes"` to start. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Read `man pm-is-supported`.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out

Answer (score 5):

It turned out to be issue with Nvidia driver 460. Updating to 465 solved all issues with sleep.

Comment: Upgrading from 470 to 510 did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: nvidia-driver-525 suffers from the same issue. Had to downgrade to 510 to resolve.